# DataTables, PDF and special characters

Tags: character-encoding

I am using DataTables and the TableTools PDF export function. The PDF-export does not take care of certain special characters and translate them into rubbish (or ISO equivalences, i guess). The characters are '●' `&#9679;`, '○' `&#9675;`, and '‭٭‭' `&#1645;`.

Is there any way to define the character set for the PDF so I can preserve those special characters? (I'm guessing that character set is the problem) Or any other workaround?

Comment: Note the use of the Unicode U+202D "left-to-right override" characters to get that third special character to behave. It's needed because the character in question is Arabic punctuation and thus uses right-to-left layout by default.

Comment: Okay? Thank you. Havent noticed any problems using it myself, though, in `<td>`'s or `<span>`'s (and do certainly not write right-to-left). In fact, those characters is used to reproduce the symbols found in scientific publications that show species tabkes of spiders, beetles etc, their findings, when they are first found and so on..

Comment: And why exactly should this one be downvoted?

Comment: Just to clarify to visitors: this is the legacy datatables pdf export using flash. For similar questions with modern versions of datatables and the HTML5 export options see eg  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548170/changing-font-in-datatables-pdfmaker-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late answer (to my self) but others could benefit. I figured out to use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) instead. It supports UTF8, languages with special characters and embedded stylesheets.

Comment: Can you share how to integrate mPDF to the TableTools? I have the same problem with TableTools, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lenciel, I did not integrate mPDF in TableTools. Ended up just using mPDF. TableTools is great but appearently not adequate when you deal with special or national characters. But it is a good idea as a hobby project, though, integrating datatables and mPDF. Sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to configure the character set for the PDF. DataTables, or specifically its TableTools add-on, uses a fairly limited Flash-based PDF exporter.

You can, however, edit the ActionScript used to make the TableTools Flash add-on.

[Download](http://datatables.net/download/) TableTools and look in the archive's `\media\as3` directory for `.as` files.

If you don't have Adobe's software for Flash authoring, you might try the open source [Adobe Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex).