# Changing font in datatables pdfmaker extension

Tags: pdf, fonts, datatables

I have googled enough for a whole one day, and searched StackOverflow to find a solution for changing the font in pdf exports of dataTables. However, I didn't run into a solution. When I export the table into pdf script fonts are something undecipherable. Just look at the picture below. It shows two columns from my table.

[image: PDF export of datatables font problem]

Both dataTables forum and pdfMaker documentations are vague. Can anyone please help me out of the problem. I need to specify a font for pdfMaker extension of datatables.
The following is what vfs_fonts.js looks like:

```js
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
 pdfMake.fonts = {
        Vazir: {
                normal: 'Vazir-FD.ttf',
                bold: 'Vazir-FD.ttf',
                italics: 'Vazir-FD.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'Vazir-FD.ttf'
        }
};
}
```

The following is also my buttons block of my datatables:

```js
buttons: [
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', exportOptions:
                        { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
                    customize: function (doc) {
                    doc.defaultStyle.font = Vazir},

                },
 ]
```

Note that in the above block of code, when I add 'customize' block, the pdfMaker button won't prepare any pdf reports; without it, it works, however, the fonts are undecipherable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the original data look like? Can you provide a small sample? (Something in a Persian font, I am guessing...)

Comment: Definitely dear. It is a table with Persian fonts. Everything is fine with the table. There is no problem with print, excel, and copy buttons in datatables. However, when datatables makes a pdf version of the table, the font can not be embedded and the result is what you can see in the picture above. What kind of sample do you need? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution.

### The DataTable Code

The HTML is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Export to PDF</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- buttons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>

  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  
  <!--
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

  Build a custom local version of the vfs_fonts.js file, containing whatever fonts you need. The 
  structure of the file is this:
  
  this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
    "arial.ttf": "AAEAA...MYXRu",
    "another_one.ttf": "XXXX...XXXX"
  };

  Replace the "AAEAA...MYXRu" with the base64-encoded string of your font file.
  You can use this site to generate the string: https://dataurl.sveinbjorn.org/#dataurlmaker

  -->
  <script src="vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display nowrap dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Adélaïde Nixon</td>
                <td><font face="verdana">الفبای فارسی ۱۲۳۴</font></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Data</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({

      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'pdf',
        customize: function ( doc ) {
          processDoc(doc);
        }
      }]
    });
  });

  function processDoc(doc) {
    //
    // https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/
    //
    // Update pdfmake's global font list, using the fonts available in
    // the customized vfs_fonts.js file (do NOT remove the Roboto default):
    pdfMake.fonts = {
      Roboto: {
        normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
      },
      arial: {
        normal: 'arial.ttf',
        bold: 'arial.ttf',
        italics: 'arial.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'arial.ttf'
      }
    };
    // modify the PDF to use a different default font:
    doc.defaultStyle.font = "arial";
    var i = 1;
  }

</script>

</body>
```

### The DataTable as a Web Page

The above HTML produces the following web page:

[image]

### The PDF File

When you click on the "Save as PDF" button, the PDF document looks like this:

[image]

### How to Implement

As explained [here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/), pdfMake uses the Roboto font by default. This font does not support Persian characters/script. To work around this, I changed the default font to Arial, which does provide support for Persian characters/script.

**Please see the additional notes at the end regarding the use of Arial - another font may be more appropriate to avoid licensing issues.**

To make this change I took the following steps:

I generated a new `vfs_fonts.js` file, containing the contents of an arial TTF file. I also refer to this new local `vfs_fonts.js` file, instead of the Cloudflare version.

The `vfs_fonts.js` file has the following structure:

```
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
  "arial.ttf": "AAEAA...MYXRu",
  "another_one.ttf": "XXXX...XXXX"
};
```

Each of the `"AAEAA...MYXRu` strings is the base64-encoded representation of the related font file.

To generate the string for your TTF file, you can use the utilities provided by pdfmake (see below), or you can use any base64 encoder. One example is [dataurlmaker](https://dataurl.sveinbjorn.org/#dataurlmaker).

Paste the (very long) string generated by dataurlmaker into your `vfs_fonts.js` file. Do NOT include any preamble provided by dataurlmaker ("data:application/octet-stream;base64,"). Include only the base64 string itself.

Alternatively...

Using the tools provided by pdfmake:

To generate this new `vfs_fonts.js` file, I followed the relevant instructions on [this page](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/).

(a) I already had npm installed.

(b) I ran `npm install pdfmake`

(c) I changed to the pdfmake installation directory:

```
C:\Users\<myUserID>\node_modules\pdfmake\
```

(d) I created the `examples/fonts` subdirectory in my `pdfMake` directory.

(e) I copied my Windows `arial.ttf` file into this new `fonts` directory.

(f) I ran `npm install` (from the pdfMake directory) to ensure all prerequisites modules were installed.

(g) I installed gulp using `npm install gulp --global`

(h) I ran `gulp buildFonts` to create a new `build/vfs_fonts.js`.

(i) I included this new `build/vfs_fonts.js` file in my web page code (as shown above).

After taking these steps, I was able to generate a PDF using the Arial font.

---

**Update**

Please read the [comments provided by @anotherfred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548170/changing-font-in-datatables-pdfmaker-extension/60555869#comment123113116_60555869) for some important notes:

Regarding the specific use of Arial (emphasis is mine):

> *Note that Arial's licence ***may forbid this***. Fonts like Noto Sans are free international fonts but you have to carefully choose the version to get the languages you want.*

You can use online tools such as [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to find fonts which match your language & character/glyph requirements.

Regarding how to reference your chosen font file(s):

> *Also, to avoid having to set the default font in datatables options, you can just name your key in `pdfMake.fonts` Roboto (whatever ttf files you actually use in it) and it will be used automatically.*

It would be great if the following could be usd out-of-the-box in a future version of DataTables (with an upgraded version of pdfmake)

> *You can also use a font url instead of vfs_fonts, but this requires a newer version of pdfMake than datatables suggest.*

Comment: Dear Andrew James, I am so impressed. You did a really great job, and spend much time on solving the problem. Yet, may you please do me a favor, and tell me if the task is possible without that npm job. How can I introduce fonts to pdfmake without installing pdfmake itself? I mean just by editing pdfmake.js and vfs_fonts.js? Then can you please copy the content of your vfs_fonts.js as well. Millions of thanks offered.

Comment: I have made some changes to the process. (1) Now, you no longer need to edit the `pdfmake.min.js` file - just use the Cloudflare file. (2) I provided instructions on how to build a custom `vfs_fonts.js` file without needing to install any new software. You can use an online tool such as dataurlmaker (link provided in the answer above).

Comment: Dear Andrew James, words fail me to appreciate what you did. You are the only person in this vast world to opted to help. I used the dataurl as you recommended, and then changed the font name in pdfmake.js and used that in vfs_fonts.js, and it worked perfectly. Millions of thanks offered. All the best.

Comment: By the way, I am so sorry for not being able to vote for your answer. It's because of lack of reputation. With only reputation of 11, my votes are recorded, yet not shown publically.

Comment: No problem. You are very welcome. I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Dear AndrewJames. Applying your first strategy, the font characters are alright. However, there happens to be another strange problem. Can you please help me with this. Compare your two pictures, please? In the first, it is written 'الفبای فارسی 1234' while the second reads '4321 فارسی الفبای'. it is like trying to write 'He is 123' in English and result in having '321 is He'. Can you please help. Millions of thanks offered in advance.

Comment: @H.Mousavi - I don't know the answer, but it is probably because of how different applications handle RTL characters. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) and [here](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/kb/how-to-display-right-to-left--rtl---writing-direction-pdf-files-in-correct-rtl-display-direction-under-facing-or-continuous-facing-mode.php). This is a new/different problem - so, you can search for relevant answers on this site, or you can ask a new question, if you cannot find an existing answer.

Comment: An excellent answer. Note that Arial's licence may forbid this. Fonts like Noto Sans are free international fonts but you have to carefully choose the version to get the languages you want. Also, to avoid having to set the default font in datatables options, you can just name your key in pdfMake.fonts Roboto (whatever ttf files you actually use in it) and it will be used automatically. You can also use a font url instead of vfs_fonts, but this requires a newer version of pdfMake than datatables suggest

Comment: @anotherfred - Thank you for those great comments - much appreciated. I think these could be the basis of a new answer, if you are interested in doing that. Otherwise, I would reference your notes in my answer, with attribution, so they are more prominent.

Comment: @andrewJames happy for you to include this