# Not able to export (&#8451;) in pdf using jquery datatable

Tags: datatables, export-to-pdf

Temperature (℃)
Added this in  tag. While exporting this to pdf some garbadge data is appearing.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

The `℃` symbol is a single [Unicode glyph](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2103/index.htm).

The DataTables PDF exporter uses the pdfMake utility. That uses the Roboto font by default. You can see this by opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and selecting File > Properties > Fonts.

The Roboto font has a limited set of characters:

[link to font tester](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text_type=custom&preview.text=Zero%20%C2%B0C%20is%20OK.%20Zero%20%E2%84%83%20is%20not%20OK.)

The character you want to use is not part of the font set.

[image]

**Quick Solution**

Use the degree symbol (`°`) which is part of Roboto (as shown above): `&deg;` followed by a separate `C`.

**More Complicated Solution**

Use a font which supports that symbol, such as Arial, or Courier New (I think).

See the answer to this question for further details: [Changing font in datatables pdfmaker extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60548170/12567365).