# dataTable pdf export with custom font

Tags: pdf, datatable

I am trying to export pdf data from DataTable. My table contents are in Bengali language. after export it just shows strange characters. I tried to download vfs_fonts.js and include "NikoshBAN.ttf" font to it... but still the pdf can not show the content.

```js
this.pdfMake.fonts = {
  Nikosh: {
    normal: 'public/fonts/NikoshBAN.ttf'
  }
};
```

and in dataTable button initialization i use:

```js
{
  extend: 'pdf',
  text: 'Export PDF',
  exportOptions: {columns: ':visible'},
  customize: function (doc) {        
    doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Nikosh';
  },
}
```

can anybody shows me steps to export dataTable pdf with custom font?
thanks in advance

Comment: See [Changing font in datatables pdfmaker extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548170/changing-font-in-datatables-pdfmaker-extension). In the answer to that question, I used Arial as the font to provide the missing Persian symbols. I think that _should_ cover your Bengali symbols, too. Otherwise, you can use something other than Arial, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by the following way:

1. I encode my **NikoshBAN.ttf** file using https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/
2. download the vfs_fonts.js file from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js and put as a local .js file
3. then add NikoshBAN.ttf:"<encoded value from step 1" into the vfs_fonts.js file
4. now use in dataTable file as follows:

```js
pdfMake.fonts = {
                Roboto: {
                    normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                    bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                    italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                    bolditalics: 'Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
                },
                nikosh: {
                    normal: "NikoshBAN.ttf",
                    bold: "NikoshBAN.ttf",
                    italics: "NikoshBAN.ttf",
                    bolditalics: "NikoshBAN.ttf"
                }
            };
```

5. and finally in the dataTable buttons object i use as follows:

```js
buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print',
      {
          extend: 'pdf',
          customize: function(doc) {
              doc.defaultStyle.font = "nikosh";
          }
      }
]
```

now it works like charm!!!

Comment: Apart from using a different base64 encoding tool, and starting with a pre-populated vfs_fonts.js file, this answer uses the same approach and techniques as the answer I linked to.