# DataTables files export utf-8

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to export my datatable to Excel PDF CSV. How to specify utf-8 encoding?

I following this code but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#allgps').DataTable({

        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Thai.json"
        },
        responsive: true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                charset: 'UTF-8',   
                //fieldSeparator: ';',
                bom: true,
                filename: 'EXTest',
                title: 'EXTest'
            },
            'pageLength',
            'excelHtml5'
        ],

    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
});
```

Comment: The problem is not UTF-8 - the problem is font-related. To export to PDF, you need to ensure the PDF uses a font which can display Thai characters. By default, the [Roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text_type=custom&preview.text=Thai%20text%20%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A9%E0%B8%B2%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%A2%20OK%3F) used only supports a limited set of characters. You can fix this by [Changing the font in the DataTables pdfmaker extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555869/12567365).

Comment: There are some additional problems with the code in the question - for example (1) You need to use the full language URL `"https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Thai.json"` - note the use of `https:` here; (2) The code is using some non-existent options such as `charset` and `bom`. Maybe some other issues, also.